# how i can run case when with diferent nchar vector

Tags: r, case

I have this data frame. I need to substr *fecha_nacimiento* but it has 7 or 8 char.

| fecha_nacimiento | n |
| --- | --- |
| 1011997 | 1 |
| 31122002 | 2 |

i try this

```
fecha_nacimiento <- fecha_nacimiento %>% 
  mutate(year = case_when(nchar(fecha_nacimiento$fecha_nacimiento == 7 ~ substr(fecha_nacimiento, 4, 7))),
                          nchar(fecha_nacimiento$fecha_nacimiento == 8 ~ substr(fecha_nacimiento, 5, 8)))
```

But there is an error in MUTATE.

I wish to get the next formate

| fecha_nacimiento | n | days | month | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1011997 | 1 | 1 | 11 | 1997 |
| 31122002 | 2 | 31 | 12 | 2002 |

What i can do?

Comment: You didn't seem to close the opening `nchar(` parenthesis. Also when using `dplyr` commands, do not use the table name with the dollar sign -- `fecha_nacimiento$`. All variables will be looked up the data.frame you pass to the command.

Comment: Why does `1011997` split into 1 `days` and 11 `month`?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann well i trying to figured out if the fist two char are days or months, that why im trying to split the char too take a closer look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's simpler to first make every sample in `fecha_nacimiento` to the same number of characters and then work from it. Also, if you are using `dplyr`, you don't need to specify the dataframe name inside the operations (`fecha_nacimiento$fecha_nacimiento` would be wrong).

```
library(dyplr)

fecha_nacimiento %>% # First, get every string to the same n characters
  mutate( ifelse(nchar(fecha_nacimiento) == 7, # if nchar 7
    paste('0',fecha_nacimiento,''), # add 0 to beginning
    fecha_nacimiento) %>% # or skip
  # Now the new colums
  mutate(
    day = substr(fecha_nacimiento, 1, 2),
    month = substr(fecha_nacimiento, 3, 4),
    year = substr(fecha_nacimiento, 5, 8)
  )
```